# CouchDB: Trigger event when user logs in

Tags: couchdb

**USE CASE**

Replicating Inboxes or “Idle users are free” referenced here: http://blog.couchbase.com/what%E2%80%99s-new-apache-couchdb-011-%E2%80%94-part-three-new-features-replication

In a database-per-user CouchDB architecture, it would be great to only trigger replication between a user's database and an "inbox" or "master" database when a user logs in so that you don't waste resources by running continuous replication on an inactive database all the time. Also, in my application design I would love to delete/archive an inactive user's database and only restore/create it if they login after a long absence.

**PROBLEM**

It doesn't look like the _session database supports the _changes API for monitoring when new sessions occur. The only thing I can think of is using a document update handler to update a "last_login" timestamp on a user document and then watch _changes on the _users database. I don't like this approach because it means adding custom logic on the client side.

**QUESTION:**

Is there a CouchDB API for triggering events when a user logs in?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such. CouchDB currently has three types of auth: Basic, Cookie, OAuth (+ Facebook via plugin). May be, if it was possible to emit such event for Cookie and OAuth, but not for Basic since it's just a regular request with special header contained credentials against some url. In other words, even if `_session` resource will raise some event on user log in, it's possible to workaround such logic.

We had tried to solve same problem not a long time ago, but had decided, that it just worth nothing and doesn't solves our actual problems: we still have come to situation where user is anonymous and user is known one.

P.S. But you still could parse CouchDB logs, raise events on some condition and pass them to redis or MQ service to further processing, but beware of rapidly disk space run out.

Comment: +1 Thanks Kxepal. I assumed there was nothing available at the moment, but I am going to leave this question open in case that changes.

Comment: Btw, why not to create [feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB) about then?(;

Comment: I think I will! It'd be great to poll /_session/_changes for when new sessions are accessed and when old sessions are no longer valid.